# How to handle multiple clipping rectangles in a CanvasItem?

Tags: godot

Let's say I have a CanvasItem that needs to draw the background first, occupying the entire item rect, and then draw all its content within a smaller rect leaving a margin.

How should this be done in the `NOTIFICATION_DRAW` within `_notofication`?

This is what I've tried:

```
void MyCustomItem::_notification(int p_what) {

    case NOTIFICATION_DRAW: {
        // Enable clipping
        VisualServer::get_singleton()->canvas_item_set_clip(get_canvas_item(), true);

        draw_background();

        // Clip to margins
        VisualServer::get_singleton()->canvas_item_set_custom_rect(get_canvas_item(), true, Rect2(
            Point2(
             MARGIN_LEFT,
             MARGIN_TOP
            ),
            Size2(
             width - MARGIN_LEFT - MARGIN_RIGHT,
             height - MARGIN_TOP - MARGIN_BOTTOM
            )
        ));

        draw_stuff();
    }
```

The problem with this is that it will clip everything to the margins including the background.